# Adding ImageIcon to a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

Is this the correct way to add an ImageIcon to a JLabel? It doesn't seem to be working when I call the second method.
What type should addCarIcon() be?

```
  //return JLabel that is null
        JLabel findEmptySpace() 
        {

            return parkingSpace[emptySpaceNo()];
        }

        //set icon JLabel
        void addCarIcon() 
        {
            ImageIcon carIcon = new ImageIcon("car.png");
            findEmptySpace().setIcon(carIcon);
        }
```

Comment: The JLabel is not null, it just contains no ImageIcon. It is returned so an ImageIcon can be set to it in addCarIcon(). The parkingSpace JLabel is already added to the JPanel and is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```java
//return JLabel that is null
JLabel findEmptySpace() 
{
    return parkingSpace[emptySpaceNo()];
}

//set icon JLabel
void addCarIcon() 
{
    // ImageIcon carIcon = new ImageIcon("car.png");
    ImageIcon carIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("car.png"), null);
    findEmptySpace().setIcon(carIcon);
}
```

I do not reccomend to use *ImageIcon(String filename)* construction in case of problem, depending on file pakaging. It could work when you run it from IDE, and not work whe you run it from runnable jar.

*P.S.* Some time ago, I've created *IconManager* utils to use ico files instead of set of png files. You can test it, maybe it could be useful for you. (This is a link to GitHub: https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/IconManager)